# Strange Exception while working with EWS

Tags: java, exchangewebservices

I'm creating a project to get emails from exchange server. I'm taking the EWS help to get this job done.

I've the below dependencies added to my pom.xml

```
<dependencies>    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.10</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.ews-java-api</groupId>
            <artifactId>ews-java-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

In my code I'm getting the below `import` errors.

> The import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.ExchangeService
>   cannot be resolved
>
> The import
>   microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.enumeration.misc.ExchangeVersion
>   cannot be resolved

And also , I'm getting an error on my package and it reads as below.

> The type
>   microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.enumeration.misc.ExchangeVersion
>   cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class
>   files

when I opened my decencies tree, I'm surprised to see `core.ExchangeService` available(please see the below screenshot). But the `core.enumeration.misc.ExchangeVersion` is missing.

[image]

please let me know how can I fix these issues.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an Eclipse bug, though restarting Eclipse worked great for me, hope this helps somebody else too.
See [http://dev-answers.blogspot.de/2009/06/eclipse-build-errors-javalangobject.html][1] for a possible solution, otherwise try the following;

```
Close the project and reopen it.
Clean the project (It will rebuild the buildpath hence reconfiguring with the JDK libraries)
```

OR

```
Delete and Re-import the project and if necessary do the above steps again.
```

OR

If anything not working please try with other IDE it might work.

Comment: Thanks for that quick tip friend, I've tried all, and posted here when I didn't find any solution.

Comment: I think u tried maven clean also then if not then try this also. If u have any other IDE other than eclipse plz try it once.

Answer (score 0):

This bug arises when Eclipse is unable to import the jars properly. Along with the fix mentioned by [Maheshwar Ligade](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3187349/maheshwar-ligade) above, you may also try removing the import statements from code, saving it, re adding the import code & then saving it again.